# Vue.js Error "missing param for named route "editarProductos": Expected "id_producto" to be defined"

Tags: html, django, vue.js

While configuring HTML buttons in vue.js, I got a warning in console: **missing param for named route "editarProductos": Expected "id_producto" to be defined** Checking my code, I could infer that I got an issue with slot and slot-scope. Right now I'm working with @vue/cli 5.0.8

Also, in the line "data.item.id" from code down below, "data" reflects a error: "Property 'data' may not exist on type 'Vue3Instance<{ fields: { key: string; label: string; }[]; productos: never[]; },"

I hope u guys could help me, THANKS...

//C O D E//

```
 <template slot="action" slot-scope="data">
   <b-button
     size="sm"
     variant="primary"
     :to="{ name:'editarProductos', params: { id_producto: data.item.id } }"
   >
     Editar
   </b-button>
   <b-button size="sm" variant="danger">
     Eliminar
   </b-button>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
 data() {
   return {
     fields: [
       { key: 'nombreProd', label: 'Nombre' },
       { key: 'precioProd', label: 'Precio' },
       { key: 'contenido', label: 'Contenido neto' },
       { key: 'descripcionProd', label:'Descripción' },
       { key: 'action', label:'' }
     ],
     productos: []
    };
  },
},
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem in your code (maybe you are new to vue, it's ok keep it up and you can make it)

For your problem: You don't need `data` prefix just `item.id` is enough, see this example: https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#api-styles

And if this still not work then make sure that your params(`id_producto`) is not required, see this: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/route-matching-syntax.html#optional-parameters